# Does AWS Elastic Beanstalk deployment duration depend on the instance type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I cannot seem to find any evidence that supports whether this is a true statement or not. I want to know if AWS Beanstalk deploys are faster with more expensive instance types. Any thoughts are welcomed! My assumption is that it *shouldn't* matter, but my deploys are incredibly slow and I want to see how this can be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying EC2 instance definitely matters when it comes to the speed of deployment. Elastic Beanstalk is just an API service that receives and processes API calls, and provisions the underlying infrastructure. However, all the installation and configurations are done on the instances at the end of the day. Beanstalk runs a bunch of wrapper scripts in addition to user data on the instance and this is where the compute power comes into play. Moreover, some instances spin up faster than the others.

Having said that, this is definitely not the only factor. Your source bundle size, what region you are deploying to and a few other factors also play a role.